# Unable to access site via python-requests (blocked?)

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website with `requests` and `bs4`.

When I am trying to access any of the pages in this site, all that is returned to me is something called "To prove that you are a human etc.".

I have tried using headers and proxies, but I get the same message everytime.

Is it safe to assume that this site has blocked `python-requests`?

Note: I have tried selenium, but after a few times clicking around, the site asks for human verification as well. Plus, selenium is much slower compared to requests. I need to jump around the pages of the site in order to scrape, so selenium understandably navigates around quite a few times - which probably results in a need for verification.

Comment: what site is it? try getting site's API. and maybe send some code

Comment: Do you get the captcha when you browse normally? With requests have you used the session function? This can help to make it look a little less like a bot.